# Convert certificate in PKCS12 format for tomcat / JKS Keystore

Tags: linux, tomcat, ssl, webserver

I have following wildcard certificate files from GlobalSign Authority.

```
root.crt
intermediate.crt
private.key
```

I want to configure tomcat HTTPS using above cert files. I believe Tomcat support PKCS12 format.

How do i convert those certificate files in PKSC12 format? also how do i import them in tomcat keystore, specially intermediate cert?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use openssl to create your PKCS12 file

First create a single intcacerts.pem file with your intermediate(s) and CA, pasted one after each other (they must be in PEM format).

Then call openssl

`openssl pkcs12 -export -in myservercert.pem -inkey private.key -certfile intcacerts.pem -name "aFriendlyName" -out keyandcerts.p12`

(myservercert.pem is the server certificate in PEM, intcacerts.pem contains the intermediate(s) and CA as described above, private.key is the private key associated with the server certificate)

The documentation for openssl pkcs12 is [here](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/pkcs12.html)

To convert the generated PKCS12 into a JKS keystore, do something like this

`keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore keyandcerts.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -destkeystore myJKS.jks`

Comment: How do i convert my crt file in pem? what is CA pasted one? could you please explain ?

Comment: Your crt file is probably in PEM already; open it with a text editor it should read -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE....

Comment: Create an intcacerts.pem file in which you copy-paste the content of intermediate.crt and root.crt (which should be your CA certificate)

Comment: Yes both root and intermediate file has -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- and END----. You want me to do cat intermediate.crt root.crt > intcacerts.pem

Comment: What stands for **myservercert.pem** here ?

Comment: What is the proper order for joining crt files? From last to root or from root to last ?

Comment: @boraldomaster myservercert.pem is your server certificate. intcacerts.pem is your intermediate certs + CA cert, pasted one after each other

Comment: Does it matter what kind of certification order you have in intcacerts.pem?