# openssl export causes "No certificate matches private key"

Tags: openssl, pkcs#12

I got the following files from certificate provider.

```
my_company_2015_01_01
intermediate_pem_thawte_sslcode_1.crt
intermediate_pem_thawte_sslcode_2.crt
root_pem_thawte_sslcode_1.crt
private.key
```

Now I need to generate p12 file.
According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10330016/368532) I should do the following.

1. join some files into pem file
2. execute **openssl pkcs12 -export ...**

I tried to join files in any order but I alwys get the error

```
No certificate matches private key
```

So - please specify exactly how should I join my files and what should I use as private.key

Comment: Did you create a private key and CSR?  Did you send the CSR to Thawte?  I'm not sure why Thawte sent you a private key.  You should use the private key you generated before sending the CSR.